# What is the difference between ID and databaseID in the GitHub GraphQL API?

Tags: github, github-api

I am working on a new integration with [GitHub API v4](https://developer.github.com/v4/) (the one using GraphQL).

I see for example that [the User object](https://developer.github.com/v4/object/user/) has the fields `id` and `databaseid`.

What is the difference between them?

Which should I use?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `id`, because GitHub Documentation is using the `id`.

You can read more here: https://developer.github.com/v4/guides/using-global-node-ids/